# How/where to persist EventMachine object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, connection, eventmachine

I'm trying to write an application that reads data from a View and uses a controller to communicate (put / get data from a channel) with an EventMachine instance.

The design I have right now is that I will persist the EventMachine reactor and a dictionary 
that contains the ID for the event machine loop and references to the channel in/out. The event loop will connect to an IRC server and get/send requests driven by the front end.

Currently I have a view that will post to a controller that references a fixed event machine (@@myeventmachine) and a dictionary of connections (@@connections) that I defined in an initializer. The problem now seems to be that the controller/view are disposed after a single execution so I cannot store connection state in it (or can I?).

The whole idea of having something global in the application is making me cringe though, so I wonder if there's a better, more "rails like" way of persisting that information. This is my first rails/ruby project so I'm a bit lost here. Most of the information I found deals with how to use the asynchronous nature of EventMachine, and not how to persist the reactor/channels across many instances of the view/controller.